# How to add a Custom Operation in the Book Admin Edit Form's Operations?

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

As the title says I want to know how to add a ***custom operation*** in the drupal 8 ***book admin edit form's operations***. I need this for my module in which I want to provide ***Add Sub Page*** operation for the user.

[image]
Upon clicking on the operation, I want to execute a function to add a new page to the parent page. I know how to [add pages programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241767/how-to-create-and-add-a-page-to-a-book-programmatically) ([***Thanks to Lisa***](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/72086/lisa) regarding help for adding pages in the book) , the only thing that I need is this operation entry in the drop down list.

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the bookAdminTableTree() method in the BookAdminEditForm class by extending core/modules/book/src/Form/BookAdminEditForm.php with your own custom form class. You can copy the bookAdminTableTree() method's code and then add an item to the $form[$id]['operations']['#links'] array for 'add-sub-page' (or whatever you want to name the new operation.)

Then alter the existing /admin/structure/book/{node} route (book.admin_edit) in book.routing.yml with a route to your new custom form class.  See [www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) and the setDefault() method in the Route class: [api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21Route.php/class/Route/8.2.x](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21Route.php/class/Route/8.2.x)

This is a helpful tutorial that describes the overall approach: https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/drupal-8-extending-core-configuration-extending-core-forms-and-overriding-core-routes